# C# - Datetime convertion and GetDayOfYear usage fails

Tags: datetime, c#-2.0, hebrew

There's the code:

```
HebrewCalendar Heb = new HebrewCalendar();
DateTime tmp = new DateTime(1964,2,3);
MessageBox.Show(Heb.GetDayOfYear(tmp));
```

it's very basic and simple, but yet -  i get an errors:

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments..

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'

what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `HebrewCalendar`, but given the error message, I'd say that `GetDayOfYear` is returning an integer.

Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(Heb.GetDayOfYear(tmp).ToString());
```

`MessageBox.Show` doesn't know how to deal with integers.  If you convert it to a string first, it will show you the string representation.

Comment: I don't like you! :)
I, with some stupidity, assumed that the problem was with the date function, instead of with the messageBox .. thanks